# What is the Signal function (SIGINT)?

Tags: c, signals, sigint

What does this statement below do? If anyone can explain this function I would really appreciate it.

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Answer (score 13):

`SIGINT` is the interrupt signal and is raised when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Its default behavior is to terminate the process. The `SIGINT` signal can be dis-positioned, which means one can change the default behavior (by calling `sighandler`, or setting it `SIG_IGN`).

Now once the action is changed and you want to set it again the default behavior of this signal then you should write

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```

It will again change the default behavior of the signal (which is to terminate the process).

Answer (score 5):

Set the handling of the SIGINT signal to its default.

If you are on a *nix system, try `man signal` to get answers like this. That (and maybe checking some of the pages listed under "See Also") will also tell you what signals are.

As for what the defaults are - it's going to be one of "ignore it", "terminate the program", or "cause the program to dump core". Which it is depends on the specific signal, and I don't remember the default for SIGINT, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The line you wrote changes the signal handler of the interrupt signal back to the default

```
void myInterruptHandler (int signum) { 
    printf("You pressed ctrl+c, but I don't care\n");
 }

int main(){
  sighandler_t oldHandler = signal(SIGINT, myInterruptHandler);
  while(true){
    printf("Ctrl + C can't kill me!!\n");
    sleep(1000);
  }
  //Change back to the old handler
  signal(SIGINT, oldHandler);
  //alternatively:  signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
}
```

Comment: Will the above program ever let control flow to the last line?  Looks like it will be trapped in the loop.

Comment: When the custom handler returns, will it then invoke the default handler, or not?

Answer (score 2):

It sets the default action for SIGINT as described in man page below;

From Linux signal man page;

```
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

signal() function sets the disposition of the signal signum to handler, which is either SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL or the address of a programmer-defined function.

- If the disposition is set to SIG_IGN, then the signal is ignored.
- If the disposition is set to SIG_DFL, then the default action associated with the signal occurs.