# Double prompt when handling signals with readline function in C

Tags: c, shell, readline, libreadline

I am trying to write a minimal implementation of a shell for a school project. To write such an implementation I use the `readline` function and I have to handle `SIGINT` so that I display a new prompt on a new line when it occurs within the program life (which could be at two key moments that are just after the user input has been read (beginning of the `while` loop) or after the line has been executed (end of the loop).
First a minimal reproducible example of my problem (with some prints for me to better understand what happens. I left the comments explaining what I tried and will explain them right after the chunk of code you need to see to understand.

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RED "\e[0;31m"
#define GRN "\e[0;32m"
#define CRESET "\e[0m"

volatile sig_atomic_t   g_termsig;

extern char **environ;

int event_hook(void)
{
    return (0);
}

int init_sig(void (*handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void *), const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction    sa;

    bzero(&sa, sizeof sa);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    //if (sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) || sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, signum))
    //  return (1);
    return (sigaction(signum, &sa, NULL));
}

_Noreturn void  exit_message(const char *message, const int status)
{
    const char  *color;

    color = RED;
    if (! status)
        color = GRN;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s%s\n", color, message, CRESET);
    exit(status);
}

void    interrupt_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
{
    (void)info;
    (void)ucontext;
    g_termsig = 128 + sig;
    rl_done = 1;
    /*
        if (! rl_done)
            ioctl(0, TCSTI, "\n");
    */
    //fprintf(stdout, "\nThis is readline_buffer : %s\n", rl_line_buffer);
}

void    restore_display(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Here is yo signal : %d\n", g_termsig);
    g_termsig = 0;
    /*
    fprintf(stdout, "In function : %s\nThis is readline_buffer : %s\n", \
    __func__, rl_line_buffer);
    */
//  rl_replace_line("", 0);
    //fprintf(stdout, "This is the new line buffer : %s\n", rl_line_buffer);
//  rl_on_new_line();
//  rl_redisplay();
}

int     execute_line(const char *line)
{
    pid_t   child_pid;
    char    *args[2] = {(char *)line, NULL};
    int     status;

    child_pid = fork();
    /*Here we set status to 0x100 so that WIFEXITED(status) is true 
    and WEXITSTATUS(status) is -1*/
    status = 0x100; 
    if (child_pid < 0)
        exit_message("No fork my G, gotta spoon dis time\n", 1);
    if (! child_pid)
    {
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        execve(line, args, environ);
        exit_message("Dude wtf?! Is that even a real command you typed?\n", 1);
    }
    wait(&status);
    return (status);
}

int main(void)
{
    char    *line;

    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    if (init_sig(interrupt_handler, SIGINT))
        exit_message("Yo, can't setup handler my G\n", 1);
    /*
    printf("This is readline output stream : %p\n", rl_outstream);
    printf("This is the address of rl_startup_hook : %p\n", rl_startup_hook);
    printf("This is the address of rl_pre_input_hook : %p\n", rl_pre_input_hook);
    printf("This is the address of rl_event_hook : %p\n", rl_event_hook);
    */
    rl_event_hook = event_hook;
    while (1)
    {
        line = readline("Enter yo commands> ");
        if (g_termsig)
        {
            free(line);
            restore_display();
            continue ;
        }
        if (! line)
            break ;
        execute_line(line);
        //It doesn't happen with that example but in the rest of my code
        //g_termsig could be set in the execute_line function
        if (g_termsig)
            restore_display();
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    exit_message("Everything good\n", 0);
}
```

So the thing is that I wanted the readline function to quit when `SIGINT` was received. I first settled for using `ioctl` with the `TCSTI` request (which is detailed in `man 2 ioctl_tty`) to fake a user input in the handler. I finally (after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165704/readline-c-force-return-of-certain-text-in-readline) and reading a good amount of [this documentation](https://bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/readline-8.1.2/doc/readline.pdf) settled for an event hook that seems to work better.

So far so good you'll tell me (in fact I hope not and that you'll be able to correct me from here). The matter is that when I input for example `/usr/bin/cat` and kill it with `^C` then the prompts get all messed up with the commands output. For example when I run `/usr/bin/cat` and then `/usr/bin/ls` or some non working command, it doesn't matter, the prompt get messed up with the ouput.
I try a combination of rl_redisplay, rl_on_new_line and rl_replace_line functions (the only ones from readline library I am allowed to use in this project) but nothing seems to do the trick so I am a bit lost.
Thanks in advance for reading me and taking time to share your knowledge with me

Comment: have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828378/readline-get-a-new-prompt-on-sigint)?

Comment: A line editing library should not make you deal with the SIGINT signal. Find a better one.  Line editing puts the TTY in raw mode, so that Ctrl-C is received as an ordinary character.  While line editing is going on, there is no SIGINT; it is used only for interrupting the execution of the commands in your own code.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I did but I am unfortunately not allowed to use such jumps. I noticed while reading bash source code for signal handling that bash doesn't do it either so I don't think it is necessary to handle such events

Comment: @Kaz there is indeed a SIGINT when readline is waiting for user input and my handler executes properly. The thing is that I must be resetting variables in the wrong order because my prompt get messed up when I interrupt an executable launched with execve (and not when I don't launch an executable nor when my executable finishes without being interrupted)

Comment: @lazydev What if you just put the TTY into raw mode yourself around calls to readline. I wonder would readline keep that, part of the state or would it reset those states, putting the TTY in a mode where it performs Ctrl_C SIGINT?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got the answer.
The thing is that when the process was forked (let's say we ran `/usr/bin/cat`) and then interrupted with `SIGINT` the wait called failed and the parent was unwaited for (thus creating a zombie and messing will all the other wait calls). If we ran after that command, a command such as `/usr/bin/ls` the process encountered the previous zombie that had been unwaited for, returned early, printed the prompt and only after the ls command printed its output.
The solution is to set `sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART` (in function `init_sig`) so that the wait call will be restarted when `SIGINT` is received.

I hope my troubles will help some other people, thanks to those who tried to come up with hints and workarounds